# SQL TERADATA : I am looking to make create a column based on count of repetition of dates. Without any reduction on output rows

Tags: join, count, teradata

I am looking for help where I want the output as below columns highlighted in yellow COUNT_START_DATE and COUNT_END_DATE without any aggregation or other words want all the rows as it is.
The Counts are based on Key EMP_ID and NAME
and Count of columns are duplicates of the date repeated grouped by EMP_ID and NAME
[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo0w5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 2 *Group Aggregates*

```
select t.*,
   count(*) over (partition by date_start) as COUNT_START_DATE,
   count(*) over (partition by date_end) as COUNT_END_DATE,
from tab as t
```